# Why I can't find the process of the project while I attach to the remote server?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I want to debug my program on the remote server computer(Windows Server 2012R) that followed this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2019#BKMK_msvsmon

I am using the Visual Studio 2019 16.5 preview 2.0, and I have installed the Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger on the server computer already.

As you see, now I connect to the remote server successfully.

[image]

Meanwhile, I can't find the process of the project in Visual Studio of the local computer.
[image]

I have checked that the process of the project has run successfully via the Visual Studio Code on the remote server.
[image]

Why it turns out to be this? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: w3wp.exe is not running in the session of your remote debugging user account, so you must check the box "Show processes from all users".

Comment: Well, it works. The w3wp.exe belongs to the user "IIS APPPOOL". However, how can I get it directly without click the "Show processes from all users", that will loading for a long time.@LexLi

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/reattach-to-process-in-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the comments.

You might study more about Windows session isolation so as to understand how IIS worker processes are created under system session (session 0) and run under their application pool identities.

As a result, when you try to remote debug, by default you won't be able to see w3wp.exe because they don't belong to the account you log on to that machine (XX\Administrator in your case).

You have to check "Show processes from all users" and then the desired processes should appear.